# How to use Aurelia's bindable decorator on a property with getter and setter

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have no problem using the `@bindable` decorator for a property on a class. 
E.g.

```
export class SomeClass {
    @bindable public SomeProperty: Date = new Date();
}
```

But I'm stumped when it comes to using it with properties that have a getter/setter implementation. E.g.

```
export class SomeClass2 {
    // Where should the @bindable go now?
    private _someProperty: Date = new Date();

    public get SomeProperty(): Date {
        return this._someProperty;
    }

    public set SomeProperty(value: Date) {
        // Do some manipulation / validation here
        this._someProperty = value;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bindable works by adding a getter and a setter on your property that it uses for observing changes.  It's recommended that you utilize the `${propertyName}Changed(newValue, oldValue)` callback method to accomplish what you're trying to do. Here is an ES2016 example:

ViewModel

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyCustomElement {
  @bindable name;

  _name;
  errorMessage = '';

  nameChanged(newValue) {
    if(newValue.length >= 5 ) {
      this.errorMessage = 'Name is too long';
    }
    else {
      this._name = newValue;
      this.errorMessage = '';
    }
  }
}
```

View

```
<template>
  <p>Name is: ${_name}</p>
  <p>Error is: ${errorMessage}</p>
</template>
```

Note that since ES2016 doesn't have private variables, I'm able to use the private backing field in my View. I'm not sure if you can do this in TypeScript, but if you can't, do note that changing the value of the `name` property in your code will also trigger the `nameChanged` callback to fire. So you would need to check if `newValue` is equal to `this._name` and ignore it in that case.

Comment: Ah, OK - the bit about `@bindable` actually creating a getter/setter is key - didn't pick up on that - thank you! Looking at the above do we not actually have two variables (`name` and `_name`) with the `Changed` method only controlling the change cascade to the `_name` variable. Or does the `@bindable` have "magic/convention" to realise that `_name` is the backing for `name`?